# Encontrar cual es el par o impar de una cadena javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un ejercicio en el que me va a dar un string con una serie de números que van a ser todos impares excepto que va a ser par y viceversa. este me debe devolver el indice  dándome la posición en la que se encuentra (teniendo en cuenta que debe ser indexada desde 1, no desde 0).
He probado a hacer lo siguiente y funciona:

```
function detectarValorDestacado(cadena) {
    
    let ns = cadena.split(" ");
    let pares= 0;
    let impares = 0;
    let counterPares = 0;
    let counterImpares = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < ns.length; i++) {
//compruebo si la posición es par o impar
        if (ns[i]%2 === 0) { 
            pares = i + 1 //aquí lo indexo sumandole 1 para que nunca me de posición 0
            counterPares++ //aquí acumulo las veces que encuentra un par
        } else {
            impares = i + 1  //aquí lo indexo sumandole 1 para que nunca me de posición 0
            counterImpares++ //aquí acumulo las veces que encuentra un impar
        }
    }

//Si lo ha encontrado solo una vez, entonces ese es el valor que quiero
        if (counterPares === 1) {
            return pares
        } 
        if (counterImpares === 1) {
            return impares
        }
        
    }

// el tercer número es impar y el resto pares. El índice del número es el 3
console.log(detectOutlierValue("0 6 5 4 20")); // => 3 

// el segundo número es par y el resto impares. El índice del número es el 2
console.log(detectOutlierValue("3 12 5 7"))  //=> 2
```

Esto me funciona perfectamente, pero me queda la duda de si se me está escapando algo con lo que pueda optimizarlo, ya que lo veo demasiado largo... Alguien sabe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con un poco de programación funcional. Por no liarte mucho a declarar contadores y variables:

```js
function detectOutlierValue(text) {
  const cadenaList = text.split(' ');
  // Aquí haces una lista de los números que son impares
  const imparList = cadenaList.filter((n) => n % 2 !== 0);
  
  if (imparList.length === 1) {
    // Si la longitud de la lista es 1, es porque el "intruso" es el impar, buscas su posición en el array y le sumas 1
    return cadenaList.indexOf(imparList.toString()) + 1;
  } else {
    // Si no, le restas la lista resultante a la original y te quedará el par "intruso". Buscas su posición y listo
    return cadenaList.indexOf(cadenaList.filter(n => !imparList.includes(n)).toString()) + 1;
  }
}

console.log(detectOutlierValue('2 4 6 8 9')); // => 5
console.log(detectOutlierValue('1 3 5 6 7')); // => 4
```

Con esto lo harías más corto, pero no estaría tan optimizado, ya que de tu forma sólo recorres una vez el array

Comment: sí, algo así es lo que buscaba. Muchísimas gracias!